# How to assign ViewData value as div id in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, viewdata

hi friends help me to get out of this..

```
//controller
{
ViewData["idvalue"]="id"+1;
return View();
}
// Viewpage

<div id="?? "> id has to set as id1..
```

help me, how i can set div id as id1..?

thanks in advance.

regards,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
//controller
{
  ViewData["idvalue"] ="id1";
  return View();
}
// Viewpage

<div id='@ViewData["idvalue"]'>
```

However, I would recommend to use [`ViewBag`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.controllerbase.viewbag) instead of `ViewData`

Answer (score 1):

```
{
ViewBag.idvalue ="id1";
return View();
}
// Viewpage

<div id='@ViewBag.idvalue'>
```

I recommend using ViewBag instead. It's just a nicer wrapper for ViewData